# Unable to set HikariCP max-pool-size

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.3 release. I want to increase the maximum pool size of HikariCP which is 10 by default.

I tried changing it in `applicaiton.properties` with

> spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=200

but it is not working because in the logs it still show that max pool size is 10.

The reason I want to change is because I am somehow reaching that limit in staging and I have no idea what's causing it.

Comment: How are you creating the `DataSource`? Are you allowing Spring Boot to do the setup or did you override it?

Comment: can you try with spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=200

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Oh yes I was. Sorry I forgot that completely. Many thanks. Now its working.

Comment: @Lokesh updated my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [HikariCP Github README](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) it's `maximumPoolSize` so try using:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize = 200
```

But this will work only if you allow Spring Boot to create the `DataSource`. If you create the `DataSource` yourself Spring Boot properties have no effect.

Do note that 200 is a very high value that may negatively impact your database as each physical connection requires server resources. In most cases a lower value will yield better performance, see [HikariCP wiki: About Pool Sizing](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing).

Comment: It didn't work. It still shows 10. I know `100` is very high value but I have no idea what's causing the pool to reach that limit easily. Does every query creates a new connection?

Comment: @Lokesh no, queries are usually bound to logical connections not physical connections. It could be that you have a connection leak in your code. You need to close connections if you retrieve them from `DataSource` so they can be returned to the pool.

Comment: How to configure max pool size, when I create DS myself?

Comment: I am creating the datasource using given below  
  
    public DataSource docmgmtDataSource() {
        return empDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    } - here how to define the hikari pool size ?

Answer (score 24):

I faced similar issue recently (Spring Boot v2.1.3). Posting it here in case people bump into the same scenario.

**Long story short**: if you're initializing `DataSource` using `@ConfigurationProperties`, those properties don't seem to require `hikari` prefix for `maximum-pool-size`, unless I'm missing something. So `spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size` should work if you use `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")`.

**Details**: In my case I'm initializing DataSource myself using `org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder`, so that I could later use it in `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource()
{
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

In this case property `spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size` taken from [Common App Properties section in Spring Boot doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.datasource.hikari) did not help. Neither did [suggested above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53556947/4430810) `maximumPoolSize`.

So I went and debugged Spring Boot code which lead me to `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder` and it's method `bind`. Value for property name for `HikariDataSource` setter `setMaximumPoolSize` was "maximum-pool-size", so just for sake of testing I renamed my property to be `spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size` and it finally worked.

Hope it helps. Please let me know in the comments if I missed something or took wrong path. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is very detailed and helpful. I had been using `spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size` and could not understand why is it not working. `spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size` worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.emp") and i have defined app.datasource.emp.maximum-pool-size=15 in application properties even though Hikari showing as default pool size is 10 - any suggestion ?